# Packages folder is empty?

Tags: unity-game-engine, package

My entire project runs fine, but I'm trying to install and work with URP. I need to grab something from its Packages subfolder, but my entire project's Packages folder is entirely empty. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3):

It might just be the visibility toggle that's in "hide immutable mode".

All recent Unity versions hide Packages that are imported in an immutable way. In the Project View though there's an icon that tells how many items are hidden (or that could be hidden because immutable and currently visible) and a barred eye. Clicking that toggles the visibility of such items.

[image: Show hidden Packages in Unity]

Answer (score 0):

Imported packages can be found at **Library/PackageCache**. If you need to modify an asset from a package, you can move that package to **Packages** folder via file explorer.